# Chonky React: Cannot have two HTML5 backends at the same time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-dnd

## I am posting this as an ANSWER in case anyone has this (extremely...... annoying) problem in the future.

Feel free to comment and talk about why you think this is happening.

As it stands though, I am not looking for any other solutions.

**Summary of the Problem:**

1. When using Chonky v2.3.2, the Drag and Drop functionality results in an Application crash when "Dropping" an item in the File Browser.
2. The Problem changes when setting a DndProvider in the applications top level. When a DndProvider is set manually, and the native provider is disabled in the component (using "disableDragAndDropProvider={true}"), instead of crashing, drag and drop does not work at all.
3. In the component tree (react devtools) there is only one DndProvider, yet the error persists and suggests there is multiple.

**My Project Environment**

1. React + Typescript with Vite (HMR and StrictMode Enabled)
2. Multi Page, nested Router application

**The F***ing Solution :)**

1. It seems that by default Chonky will install React-dnd and React-dnd-html5-backend when first added to the project. By creating a new vite project and installing Chonky, the "Multiple DnDProvider" error immediately presents itself in a basic VFSBrowser example (can be found on the chonky demo repository).
2. Running a quick `npm list react-dnd` after chonky installation will show an already installed react-dnd instance. However, something about chonky being run with vite (possibly because of HMR or Strict Mode) causes this crashing "multi provider" bug.
3. As such, installing your own react-dnd and react-dnd-html5-backend via `npm i react-dnd` and `npm i react-dnd-html5-backend` would in theory fix your problem right? **WRONG**
4. The **solution** is installing a second DND provider of the **exact same version** contained inside chonky, causing a deduped version within chonky, and pulling the provider out of chonky into the same provider set in the applications root.
5. Once done correctly, your `npm list react-dnd` and react-dnd-html5-backed should look like

```js
├─┬ chonky@2.3.2
│ └── react-dnd@11.1.3 deduped
└── react-dnd@11.1.3`
```

6. After doing this, find your application root (main.tsx) and include the DndProvider around your application.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <App />
      </DndProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

7. Weirdly enough, if you are using typescript, you will know you did it correctly if the DndProvider component produces the following error: `Type '{ children: Element; backend: BackendFactory; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DndProviderProps<any, any>'. Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DndProviderProps<any, any>'`

If you have any questions about this feel free to ask, I will help as best I can.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), the tl;dr is yes, but post the answer as an answer to this question, don't embed the answer in the question